# append data in datable getting Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#searchresult").append("<tr><td id=''>" + data[i].landarp + "</td>" + "<td id=''>" + data[i].landarp + "</td>" + "<td id=''>" + data[i].landpin + "</td>" + "<td id=''>" + (data[i].landlot ? "Lot " + data[i].landlot : "") + "/" + (data[i].landblock ? "Block " + data[i].landblock : "") + "</td>" + "<td id=''>" + data[i].landfirstname + " " + data[i].landmiddlename + " " + data[i].landlastname + ", " + data[i].landsuffix + "</td>"
    for (var land = 0; land < landaddress.length; land++) {
        landownercontactflag = landaddress[land].landownercontactflag;
        landownercontactflag === "1" ? (contactaddress = landaddress[land].landownerprovince + " " + landaddress[land].landownermunicipality + " " + landaddress[land].landownerbarangay + ", " + landaddress[land].landownerstreet) : (homeaddress = landaddress[land].landownerprovince + " " + landaddress[land].landownermunicipality + " " + landaddress[land].landownerbarangay + ", " + landaddress[land].landownerstreet) + "<td id=''>" + landownercontactflag === "1" ? contactaddress : homeaddress + "</td>"
    } + "<td id=''>" + data[i].landyear + "</td>" + "<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"af_rpta_treasuryall_specificpin\"  id=" + data[i].landpin + " href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td></tr>");
```

Trying to append data from database using this code but then i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in this line `+"<td id=''>" + data[i].landfirstname + " " + data[i].landmiddlename + " " + data[i].landlastname + ", " + data[i].landsuffix + "</td>"` what is the cause of this and how to fix it

Comment: You are not closing the append function   ')' is missing before start of for loop.Also not closing with <tr>

Comment: You can't have a for loop inside a function call.

Comment: i see thank you Juhana that i didnt know. i think i should i just put it in a variable and use that variable what do you think?>

Comment: What is the cause of "missing ) error"? - you're missing a ")"

Comment: @freedomn-m i am not missing a ")" i checked it thoroughly i think its because of for loop inside append just like comment above ^

Comment: Can you please add data array so we can check

Comment: I think you should seriously re-consider how you build that monstrosity. At the very least add each td on a separate line, in the best case create them as jQuery elements because now if the data happens to have HTML tags inside them it'll break the code. Once you get it working I suggest you post it to the [codereview.se] site for some tips.

Comment: i will recreate this and please add comment give me more time thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove all the data specific parts, this is what you have:

```
$("#searchresult").append("text"
for (var land = 0; land < landaddress.length; land++) {
    landownercontactflag = "text";
} 
+ "text");
```

> I am not missing a ")" i checked it thoroughly i think its because of for loop inside append just like comment above

There's a missing ")" at the end of the append("text"

(you'll also notice I've changed the indentation to how it's interpreted)

Javascript does not require the use of ";" to end statements and you can use a newline to mean the same, ie these are equivalent:

```
$("#").append()
```

and

```
$("#").append();
```

because there's a newline at the end of the `append(`, it looks to see what the next *statement* is.  If this was a '+' it would continue to append the next text, but in this case, it's a new statement `for` - so javascript attempts to close off the `.append(` and gives an error that there's a missing ")".

This is the equivalent of:

```
$("#searchresult").append("text";
for ...
```

see the ";" at the end now?  As there's no ")" before the implied ";", it gives you the warning that there's a ")" missing.

If you did add the ');' at the end of the line then you'll get an error later on about the `+ ..` as there's nothing for the `+` to be +ed to.

As you've established, this is because of trying to put a command inside the brackets of another - but I wanted to explain why the interpreter thinks this way with the implied end-of-statement at a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `for` statement inside a `$("#searchresult").append(`

My suggestion is to create a variable and to populate it... then to use it inside append.

For example:

```
var myVar = "<tr><td id=''>" + data[i].landarp + "</td>" + "<td id=''>" + data[i].landarp
...
for (var land = 0; land < landaddress.length; land++) {
  landownercontactflag = landaddress[land].landownercontactflag;
  ....
  myVar = myVar + ......
  .....
}
....
$("#searchresult").append(myVar);
```

But... are you sure you really know what your "for" loop is doing?

UPDATE: as alternative (without a variable):

```
 $("#searchresult").append("<tr><td id=''>" + data[i].landarp + "</td>" + "<td id=''>" + data[i].landarp ....);
    ...
    for (var land = 0; land < landaddress.length; land++) {
      landownercontactflag = landaddress[land].landownercontactflag;
      ....
      $("#searchresult").append(".....");
    }
    ....
    $("#searchresult").append("....");
```

Comment: my data is multidimensional so i need inside for loop to get address.

Comment: Ok... but you have to add anything you need to write in the page inside one (or more) string... this because .appen(...) need a string as parameter... and you can't put a "for" statement  inside: you have to use a loop to create a variable (or to appen any single element of the loop)... Remember: only strings inside "append" (see my updated reply).

Comment: You need the `for` loop but it doesn't need to be *inside* the `append` - the solution is to build the entire html first then send it to the append.  As far as I can see, there's nothing in the build-html stage that relies on the existing values of the '#searchresult'